# Fonts for Mathematics and Text

Tags: fonts, math-mode, book-design, unicode-math, examples

Are there some examples of long, real-world documents showing the variety of text and mathematical fonts now available? With unicode-math there are now many more fonts for text and mathematics, both commercial and public-domain, than before. It is easy enough to find short examples, but what I would like to see would be different versions of a long document (e.g., an article or chapter from a book), with each version set in a different font (e.g., Lucida, Minion-Math, Latin Modern, Tex-Gyre, Mathtime, etc).

This type of question seems to come up frequently in this forum and others and I will answer it myself. However, I would also like to see other examples too.

Answer (score 18):

I have posted several versions of a couple of book chapters at the following website: 
http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/gv219/aofd/fonts/ 
There you will find the same 100-plus page document typeset with Lucida, Minion-Math, MathTime, Cambria, Tex-Gyre and others. Comments, and other examples, would be welcome.

[image: scra]
[image: scrb]

Also, as an update, for the final version of the book I ended up using Minion for text, Cronos for sans serif, and Minion-Math for math, and you can see this at http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/gv219/aofd

[image: scr1]
[image: scr2]
[image: scr3]

Comment: May I ask which font combination you went for in the end?

Comment: The first edition was written using Lucida for text and maths. I'm now preparing a second edition and will either use Lucida again or Minion plus Minion-math from typoma.com, which I like as it is elegant, readable and very comprehensive.

Comment: @GeoffV: The link is dead.

Comment: @lblb  Thanks for pointing that out. The link has moved to
http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/gv219/aofd/fonts/
I've updated the answer, too.
Also, as an update, for the final version of the book I ended up using Minion for text, Cronos for sans serif, and Minion-Math for math, and you can see this at 
http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/gv219/aofd/

Comment: @GeoffV, it's beautiful, especially the final version. I added screenshots in the post.

Comment: @lblb - Thanks! I'm not sure it will break into the New York Times bestseller list, but it was satisfying to write it and, in the end, finish it. I should also thank everyone on tex.stackexchange.com since all the various questions and answers were absolutely invaluable to me.